# Batch copy file from multiple sources via robocopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, robocopy

I am trying to write a script to copy log files from different sources and PC´s to 1 destination using robocopy.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (pc.txt) do (
set source0="\\%%a\D$\log"
set source1="\\%%a\C$\XX\log"
set source2="\\%%a\C$\XXX\log"
set dest="\\%COMPUTERNAME%\C$\XXX\logscript\%%a"
robocopy %source0% %dest% /create
robocopy %source1% %dest%
robocopy %source2% %dest%
)
```

The problem I am facing is robocopy does not get the variables the at the first run, at the 2nd run its working but when i add more PC´s to my pc.txt it only uses some pc´s names.

Comment: [Please, read this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (pc.txt) do (
    set source0="\\%%a\D$\log"
    set source1="\\%%a\C$\XX\log"
    set source2="\\%%a\C$\XXX\log"
    set dest="\\%COMPUTERNAME%\C$\XXX\logscript\%%a"

    REM Note that variables are surrounded with exclamation marks instead.
    robocopy !source0! !dest! /create
    robocopy !source1! !dest!
    robocopy !source2! !dest!
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Without this, the entire contents of the `FOR` loop are parsed only on the first pass (so your source and dest variables are not set yet). When delayed expansion is enabled, the variables are evaluated on each pass.